# is "hesitative" actually a word?

Tags: word-request

I was looking for an adjective for the verb 'hesitate' but it seems that there is not one. However, I find some people using the word 'hesitative' so is it actually a word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjective form is **[hesitant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hesitant)**.